# Sync device sqlite database rows to Google Drive

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to do something that I thought would be fairly common --

Keep a local sqlite database on a user's phone/tablet in sync with a copy that's stored in their Google Drive app folder.

The benefits are obvious -- namely a user can use multiple devices, or replace their only device, and always get the latest database information, without resorting to manual exports/imports.

For an implementation, I see that it would be fairly easy to keep some kind of hashcode and do a full database upload/download whenever something changes -- however that becomes increasingly punitive and inefficient as the database grows.

I was hoping there would be a way to sync singular row-based operations, such as:

1. Delete this row
2. Insert this row
3. Change this row

However, this appears to be non-trivial, if even possible.

What is the recommended approach for syncing row-based sqlite database operations between a device and Google Drive?

Comment: Add some kind of timestamp in each row to determine whats new/changed/deleted and keep the current version (implemented as a timestamp too) in both databases,  will it work?

Comment: @pskink, yes, I do have "updated at" timestamps on each row, but my question is more about how to perform row-based operations on a remote database stored in Google Drive.  After more research, I'm seeing that it might be best to store the data in Drive as a Google spreadsheet, and manipulate it that way.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking at the wrong api. Check out the Google Spreadsheet API